# Run jQuery function for each element separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

What do I have to add to the script to run multiple tab navigations side by side?

I have build a little tab navigation and run into problems with that, any ideas how to fix this?

Please take a look at the script below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.material--switch li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.material--switch li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('active');
  })

})
```

```css
.material--switch {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.material--switch li {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 0;
  color: #6f1132;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.material--switch li.active {
  border-color: #039BE5 !important;
  background: #039BE5;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="material--switch">
  <li class="active" data-tab="option1">option1</li>
  <li data-tab="option2">option2</li>
</ul>

<div id="option1" class="tab-content active">
  show option1
</div>

<div id="option2" class="tab-content">
  show option2
</div>


<ul class="material--switch">
  <li data-tab="option3">option3</li>
  <li class="active" data-tab="option4">option4</li>
</ul>

<div id="option3" class="tab-content">
  show option3
</div>

<div id="option4" class="tab-content active">
  show option4
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `float: left;` to both of your menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code acts against all `ul.material--switch li` elements as one set; your code doesn't have any indication that there are separate sets of tabs you want to act on.  Here I've added a `.container` div around each group, to contain the tabset and its available options; your function is run separately for each `.container` and acts only on its contents.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.container').each(function() {
    var self = $(this); // in the next line `this` will get taken over by the `li`:
    self.find('.material--switch li').click(function() {
      var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
      self.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#' + tab_id).addClass('active');
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.material--switch {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.material--switch li {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 0;
  color: #6f1132;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.material--switch li.active {
  border-color: #039BE5 !important;
  background: #039BE5;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <ul class="material--switch">
    <li class="active" data-tab="option1">option1</li>
    <li data-tab="option2">option2</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="option1" class="tab-content active">option1</div>
  <div id="option2" class="tab-content">option2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="material--switch">
    <li class="active" data-tab="option3">option3</li>
    <li data-tab="option4">option4</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="option3" class="tab-content active">option3</div>
  <div id="option4" class="tab-content">option4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<span>` element is only permitted to contain [Phrasing Cotent](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html#span-content-model)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each set in a containing div and then just change your jQuery to only target the elements within the parent of the element that's being clicked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.material--switch li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    parent.find('ul.material--switch li').removeClass('active');
    parent.find('.tab-content').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    parent.find("#" + tab_id).addClass('active');
  })

})
```

```css
.material--switch {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.material--switch li {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 0;
  color: #6f1132;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.material--switch li.active {
  border-color: #039BE5 !important;
  background: #039BE5;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <ul class="material--switch">
   <li class="active" data-tab="option1">option1</li>
   <li data-tab="option2">option2</li>
 </ul>

 <div id="option1" class="tab-content active">
   show option1
 </div>

 <div id="option2" class="tab-content">
   show option2
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <ul class="material--switch">
   <li data-tab="option3">option3</li>
   <li class="active" data-tab="option4">option4</li>
 </ul>

 <div id="option3" class="tab-content">
   show option3
 </div>

 <div id="option4" class="tab-content active">
   show option4
 </div>
</div>
```